# Does memmove shift elements (the same way a for-loop does), or does it grab an entire block of memory at once?

Tags: c++, algorithm, data-structures, time-complexity, memmove

In my algorithms class, we have to turn in algorithms for removing duplicates of a list of integers and shoot for the lowest possible complexity. In my algorithm, when I see a duplicate integer, I shift every element after that integer down one index in order to delete the duplicated element using a for-loop; like so:

```
for(int i=dup_index; i<arr_size-1; i++)
{
  arr[i] = arr[i+1];
}
```

Would it be more efficient for my algorithm to use memmove? Furthermore if it's my job to design the algorithm, and assuming memmove lowers the complexity of my algorithm, could using memmove be seen as 'cheating'?

Comment: It's going to be linear complexity either way. `memmove` *might* be faster, but then again, it might not. On most typical computers bandwidth to memory will be the main bottleneck, so the difference between the simplest code and the most carefully optimized is rarely more than 15 to *maybe* 20%.

Comment: Use 'std::move' instead of 'memmove' in C++, but neither is optimal for this problem.

Comment: The algorithm you should be concentrating on is one that minimizes the number of times items are moved *at all*. Imagine the one you're presenting with a data set where every other element (or worse, every element) is the *same* value. Moving elements that aren't supposed to be in the output result in the first place and minimizing that is somewhat the point of this exercise. (that and a decent amount of pointer-walking).

Comment: It's cheating to say that memmove reduces complexity even it would be much faster in practice. Oftentimes you are using theoretical computers whose operations are much more restricted than C to calculate complexity.

Comment: I consider using either *not* cheating. If you want to see *real* "cheating" just throw all the elements in an `std::set`. The resulting set is your answer.

Comment: @kjh can you use extra O(N) memory because there exists more efficient algorithm if you can do so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know about cheating, but `memmove` basically does what your loop does, only more efficiently.

Besides, it's one of the most basic utility functions, so I don't see why you should not use it.

As for complexity, the order of the algorithm will not change, it will simply be faster. `memmove` is implemented in assembly and tries to make full use of the alignment to copy word per word instead of byte per byte.

EDIT:

well okay, there might be cases where the manual copy might be a couple of instructions shorter than the call to `memmove`, but if you start moving data around in memory, you're doing an inherently costly operation, so optimizing a couple of CPU cycles away will not make any difference in the big picture.

If your design involves in-place moves for performance-critical data, you would be better off changing the underlying data structure for something that avoids copies altogether (list, tree, hash table, whatever).

Answer (score 0):

Your program might run faster using memmove as far as wall clock time, but your for-loop basically achieves the same thing. The algorithm complexity won't change.

Comment: Or it may run slower. There's no easy way to tell other than testing a particular combination of compiler, compiler optimization settings, and hardware.

Answer (score 0):

Functionally, memmove does exactly what your loop does. However, the compiler and/or C runtime may implement memmove using more efficient machine code. Some architectures have specialized instructions which will perform such an operation entirely in a single instruction. It may be inlined by the compiler also.

It does not change the complexity of the algorithm, it just gets it done faster.

As to whether it would be considered cheating in your assignment - that is a question for your professor, surely? No-one here can tell you that.

Comment: *"However, the compiler and/or C runtime may implement memmove using more efficient machine code."* Or it may implement it using much less efficient machine code. For example, one some platforms, the fact that integers are being used can make the move operation faster (because they meet certain alignment requirements arbitrary pointers may not) but that information is lost if you just pass a `void *` to `memmove`.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz Usually the `memmove` primitive will check pointers alignment and do its best to use machine words as buffers to minimize actual RAM read/write accesses. Only the first leading/trailing bytes will be copied with non-word accesses. Register byte shifts will be used to compensate for src/dst misalignment.

Comment: @kuroineko Right, but that means these extra checks are required where they wouldn't be if you didn't hide the type of the pointer by forcing it to be converted to a `void *`. The more information the compiler has, the better it can optimize. Using `memmove` instead of a simple copy loop hides information from the compiler, at least, it does on some real world implementations.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz I have played with custom copy routines quite a bit in the mid-90s and my conclusion is that more often than not you will produce inefficient code trying to beat the compiler at this game. You might achieve insignificant gains for a given compiler and optimization level, but the code obfuscation required is generally not worth the effort. If you're calling `memmove` a million times over to slosh a handful of bytes around, then it's the design that is at fault, IMHO.

Comment: @kuroineko I agree. I'm just saying that the naive assumption that calling `memmove` will somehow be better than a copy loop is nonsense. Modern compilers do in fact see right though simple copy loops and optimize them with no problem. If you call `memmove`, you're requiring the compiler to grok the alignment even though your conversion to `void *` hides it, otherwise you are almost guaranteed inefficient code.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz well the cost of checking the alignment is a couple of assembly instructions. If you move more than a couple of words, it becomes quite neglectible. The benefit of calling memmove is more robust and readable code. Doing memmove on performance-critical data is a nonsense in the first place. If bulky data have to be moved around, better rethink the design to use a data structure more suited to the task than trying to optimize the design fault away IMHO.

Answer (score 0):

If there are multiple duplicates than you can use a auxillary to store non duplicates :-

```
int aux[arr_size],cnt=0;

for(int i=0;i<arr_size;i++) {

   if(arr[i]!=dup) {

         aux[cnt++] = arr[i];
   }
}
```

**If you need inplace :-**

```
int i = dup_index;
int j = dup_index+1;
int dup = arr[i];

while(j<arr_size) {

  if(arr[j]!=dup) {

      arr[i++] = arr[j];

  }

  j++;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Library functions (like `memmove(3)`) are carefully optimized. If you look at how your favorite compiler writes that out into assembly language for various lengths (given as constants) you'll probably get a huge surprise.

That said, copying $n$ bytes from one place to the other will take time $\Theta(n)$, unless you know something that helps avoid part of the shuffling data around that doesn't just cut it down by a fixed fraction.

Answer (score 0):

Updating an old answer: these days there is no doubt you are better off using built-in memmove, memcpy etc. as these will most likely be optimised to take advantage of CPU features like caching and SIMD (single instruction, multiple data), which can move or copy large blocks of bytes using a single CPU instruction.